# Create a new instance of a form and keep it open

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, program-entry-point, lifecycle

I have created two projects. One of the projects is the StartUp project. And the other is the GUI. I am trying to start the form in GUI though the StartUp project (referencing GUI).

StartUp Project:

```
Imports Container

Module modMain
    Sub main()
        Shell.Start()
    End Sub
End Module
```

GUI Project:

```
'----------------Form File------------------

Public Class Container

End Class

'----------------Shell File------------------

Public Class Shell
    Private Shared container_ As New Container

    Public Shared Sub Start()
        container_.Controls.Add(host_)
        container_.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Shared host_ As Panel

    Private Sub InitLayout()

        host_ = New System.Windows.Forms.Panel()
        Dim btn As New Button()
        btn.Text = "Click me"
        host_.Controls.Add(btn)

    End Sub

End Class
```

When I run it the form appears for only a few seconds then immediately closes. (I think) This is because I have not put any closing handlers but I am unsure how to do this.

The aim is to keep it open until the user closes it.

Comment: The form shows that is not the issue. The issue is that it immediately closes.

Comment: Then I add a breakpoint the code simple opens the form (at container_.Show()) then the end sub routine and it goes back to the modMain and then closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the form is closing is because your application is closing which in turn closes all the open forms.

Try specifying a form using [Application.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.run%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Something like this:

```
Module modMain
    Sub Main()
        Dim guiForm As Form = Shell.MainGuiForm
        Application.Run(guiForm)
    End Sub
End Module
```

You will need to have a reference to the form in your Shell class:

```
Public Class Shell
    Private Shared _container As New ContainerForm
    Public Shared ReadOnly Property MainGuiForm As Form
        Get 
            Return _container
        End Get
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I was thinking too hard. :)